# VBA Excel: How to put a value into a cell using two variable as its location

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take variant 'row' and 'column' and use them to input an "x" into the cell. 'row' and 'column' have numbers stored in them.
[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

```
Private Sub CheckInButton_Click()

Dim found_name As Range
Dim name_to_find As String
Dim row As Variant
Dim column As Variant
Dim ColLetter As Variant
Dim xLocation As Excel.Range

row = 0
column = 0

name_to_find = Worksheets("Forms").Range("N5").Value

Set found_name = Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Range("A:A").Find(what:=name_to_find,LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not found_name Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox (name_to_find & " found in row: " & found_name.row)
    row = found_name.row
    MsgBox (row)
Else
    MsgBox (name_to_find & " not found")
End If

event_to_find = Worksheets("Forms").Range("N3").Value
Set found_event = Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Range("A1:DZ1").Find(what:=event_to_find, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
MsgBox (found_event)

If Not found_event Is Nothing Then
    ColLetter = Split(found_event.Address, "$")(1)
    MsgBox (event_to_find & " found in column: " & ColLetter)
    column = found_event.column
    MsgBox (column)
Else
    MsgBox (event_to_find & " not found")
End If

Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Cells(column & row).Value2 = "x"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Cells takes two arguments, the row and the column. The & operator concatenates two values, so you're just giving .Cells one argument, the row appended to the column.

Just change `Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Cells(column & row).Value2 = "x"` to `Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Cells(row, column).Value2 = "x"`

Comment: You'd better elaborate more on *you're just giving .Cells one argument, the row appended to the column*. The thing is that OP will get correct *physical* result, but incorrect *logical* one. When OP concatenates row and column, he essentially gets **single cell**. For instance, `Dim x, y: x = 50: y = 100: MsgBox Cells(x & y).Address(0, 0)` will show `AJL4` - the address of single cell.

Comment: Well, it looks like if you give a single argument, it takes that column in the first row, looping around to the next row every 16384 (the max number of columns). For example, `MsgBox Cells(16385).Address` returns A2. I can't imagine that would be very useful to most people though, and that certainly isn't what OP's trying to do.

Comment: *and that certainly isn't what OP's trying to do* This is what I was actually talking about - you just should explain better so that OP would understand consequences. Yes, technically this notation `Cells(some_number)` is correct, but it's required to understand that the number is the number of cell calculated by going left->right->down. 

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Cells()`.

```
Cells(row, column).Value = "X"
```

So, in your case:

```
Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Cells(row, column).Value = "x"
```